# Android: Navigation Drawer activity - "The following classes could not be instantiated:"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i make a new navigation drawer activity in android studio i get the following error...

Rendering Problems

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Exception Details:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutImpl
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:148)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:195)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:191)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:152)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:78)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ProjectClassLoader.java:108)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:173)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:96)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:401)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:604)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:546)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:541)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anyone get any idea on how to find away around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to include the v4 support libraries in the dependencies.

Check [this page](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) for detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

right click your project >> go to android tools >> click add support library.

Comment: How would i do that in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code segment into your build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "26.+"
        }
    }
}}
```